How to parallelize scipy.optimize basinhopping?
I am performing many optimizations on a vector of about 100 values, with the optimization inputs changing each timestep, based on the previous timestep's optimization's results.
Optimization is done using Scipy.Optimize.Basinhopping. Each optimization step takes 10-20 seconds to run. Is it possible to parallelize Basinhopping to run a single optimization across multiple cores, and therefore speed up each step? I can't seem to find an example of this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The execution time can be slow either because of the Scipy algorithm or your user function. If this is the user function which is slow, then we need to see the code of this function so to help you to parallelize it. If this is the Scipy algorithm, then this is AFAIK not possible to parallelize it (at least, not yet). Most optimization algorithms are not easy to parallelize or even not possible to parallelize it at all (without changing them drastically and even impacting significantly the results). So in this case, the best option is certainly so choose another approach/algorithm.

Help us to help you. Show us the code you're running. Edit the Question so it is reproducible by SO contributors.

I second the previous comments. In addition, is there any reason why you are using BasinHopping? As far as I know, other algorithms like differential_evolution and SHGO in SciPy can run parallel functions evaluations. Be careful though, last time I tried, that SHGO will be a memory hog if you have more than 10 parameters.

Do you have a jac for your function? If not, and the function has a high number of variables, then parallelizing jac can help, using something like optimparallel for the internal minimizer step.
